# Error al servicio en ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedure, servicio

estoy implementando un servicio en ASP.NET Core pero me da error de procedimiento , según entiendo es por el tipo de variable que estoy ingresando y yo mandaba un string en vez de int , lo cambie pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error , que mas debo implementar o cambiar para que me funcione y deje de salir ese error .También como retornaría varios return en mi postman , ose que jecute varias consultas en un solo servicio , uno por uno. Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

este es mi controlador

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Salesws.Context;
using Salesws.Models;
using Salesws.Service;
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace Salesws.RestControllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {

        private IConfiguration _config;
        //Contexto de la base de datos SVM
        private readonly SVMcontext _context;
        private readonly IFechaService _fechaService;
        private readonly ILambSelLiquidacionService _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion;
        public LoginController(IConfiguration config, SVMcontext context,IFechaService fechaService,ILambSelLiquidacionService amb_Sel_LiquidacionService)
        {
            _config = config;
            _context = context;
            _fechaService = fechaService;
            _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion = amb_Sel_LiquidacionService;
        }

        [HttpGet("liqui/{celular}/{cod_liquidacion}")]
        public ActionResult liqui()
        {
            var liqui = _iamb_Sel_Liquidacion.liquidacion();
            return Ok(liqui);
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi repository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILambSelLiquidacionRepository
    {
        int liquidacion();
    }
}
```

este mi servicio

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILambSelLiquidacionService
    {
        int liquidacion();
    }
}
```

implemento mi servicio

```
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Service
{
    public class AmbSelLiquidacionService:ILambSelLiquidacionService
    {
        private ILambSelLiquidacionRepository _liqui;
        public AmbSelLiquidacionService(ILambSelLiquidacionRepository liqui)
        {
            _liqui = liqui;
        }


        int ILambSelLiquidacionService.liquidacion()
        {
            return _liqui.liquidacion();
        }
    }
}
```

impplemento el procedure

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Salesws.Context;
using Salesws.Service.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Salesws.Models
{
    public class AmbSelLiquidacionRepository:ILambSelLiquidacionRepository
    {
        private readonly SVMcontext _context;


        public AmbSelLiquidacionRepository(SVMcontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public int liquidacion()
        {
            int liqui = 0;
            using (DbCommand command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "dbo.amb_sel_liquidacion";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _context.Database.OpenConnection();
                using (var resultado = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (resultado.Read())
                    {
                        liqui = (int)resultado[0];
                    }
                }
                _context.Database.CloseConnection();
            }
            return liqui;
        }
    }
}
```

este es el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu error indica que tu sp espera un parámetro y no se lo estas enviando en la consulta, intenta algo así, `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cod_liquidacuib", tuValor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El servidor de base de datos está esperando que el parámetro p_cod_liquidacion sea suministrado.

debes intentar con algo como esto:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@p_cod_liquidacion", 12345);
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

o puedes hacer esto:

> `command.CommandText = "dbo.amb_sel_liquidacion(12345)";`

pero es susceptible de inyección SQL.